# Alterar cor de vários Panel's dinamicamente

Tags: vb.net, visual-basic-6, panel

Tenho o seguinte código na ação do botão:

```
 pnl1.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange
 pnl2.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange
 pnl3.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange
 pnl4.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange
 pnl5.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange
 pnl6.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange
 ... tenho 100 Panel'seguinte
```

Repetir o código 100x se torna ridículo além de inviável, o que pensei foi algo parecido com isso:

```
For i = 0 to 100    
     (pnl+i.toString).BackColor = Color.DarkOrange
Next
```

Assim funcionaria melhor...

Mas não estou conseguindo, pensei até em Macro Substituição mas ainda não conheço muito bem a linguagem.

Desde já obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isso é percorrer os [controles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection(v=vs.90).aspx) do formulário e verificar se é um `Panel`, se for, você executa a ação.

```
For Each pnl As Control In Me.Controls
   If TypeOf (pnl) Is Panel Then
     pnl.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange
   End If
Next
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Consegui tratar dessa forma!

Answer (score 1):

Um jeito bem simples:

```
For Each pI As Panel In MyClass.Controls
    pI.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange
Next
```

Se quiser para um grupo de panels:

```
Dim PaneisParaEditar As Panel() = { Pane1, Panel2, Panel3 }
For Each pI As Panel In PaneisParaEditar
    pI.BackColor = Color.DarkOrange
Next
```